# Run multiple capybara tests without reloading page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Is there anyway to load a page in capybara in a before :all block, and then run each test on the same page?

It seems right now at the end of each test the page is unloaded, so I have to do the setup in a before :each block, which really slows things down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by not requiring capybara/rspec and instead implementing you're own before after blocks and RSpec configuration that don't call Capybara.reset_sessions, however that defaults the whole concept of tests being independent, and potentially also makes your tests order dependent which really isn't a good idea. 
  If your issue is logging in each time you should look into fast tracking the login (for instance test mode in  Devise - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara)

Comment: Tom - agree with your caveats.  This is specifically for a large suite of integration tests on a large SPA that is just making stateless checks that components are there and working with correct defaults.  I think a good "litmus" test is order independence - if the test order doesn't matter than it "might" be okay to not page reset.